# Reading and organizing file lines C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file, sorting, lines

I recently started using files and I'm having some troubles implementing them in my main college project.

The following code times how long you take to type a number and hit enter, and writes the user's name, gender and time in a file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int LinesCounter(string filename)
{
    ifstream b_file(filename);

    // new lines will be skipped unless we stop it from happening:    
    b_file.unsetf(ios_base::skipws);

    // count the newlines with an algorithm specialized for counting:
    unsigned line_count = count(
        istream_iterator<char>(b_file),
        istream_iterator<char>(),

        '\n');

    return line_count;

}

int main()
{
        //Starts timing
    clock_t begin = clock();

    int letter;
    cin>>letter;
    cin.ignore();


    //Obtains the total amount of seconds taken
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed_secs = double(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout << "\nCongratulations, you took " <<elapsed_secs <<" seconds." <<endl <<endl;

    cout<<"Insert your name: ";
    string name;
    getline(cin, name);
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"M/F: ";
    char sex;
    cin >> sex;
    cout<<endl;
    cin.ignore();

    int NumberOfLines = LinesCounter("Times.txt");

    if (NumberOfLines < 10)
    {
        ofstream a_file ( "Times.txt", ios::app );

        a_file<<name <<"  " <<sex <<"  " <<elapsed_secs <<"s" <<endl;

        a_file.close();
    }


    cin.get();
}
```

The code is supposed to store only 10 times (10 lines with name, gender and time) and has to sort out the list depeding on the time. That way, the 1st line of the file should have the fastest time (and the respective user's name and gender) and the last the slowest time. 
Example:

1)
"Times.txt"

1. John M 1.449s
2. Liz F 1.552s
3. Elias M 1.788s

New time: Albert M 1.522s

"Times.txt" - Updated

1. John M 1.449s
2. Albert M 1.522s
3. Liz F 1.552s
4. Elias M 1.788s

2)
"Times.txt"

1. John M 1.449s
2. Albert M 1.522s
3. Liz F 1.552s
4. Elias M 1.788s
5. Rob M 1.819s
6. Joe M 1.842s
7. Ash M 1.893s
8. Sansa F 2.108s
9. Snow M 2.134s
10. Andy M 2.333s

New time: Ana F 1.799s

"Times.txt" - updated

1. John M 1.449s
2. Albert M 1.522s
3. Liz F 1.552s
4. Elias M 1.788s
5. Ana F 1.799s
6. Rob M 1.819s
7. Joe M 1.842s
8. Ash M 1.893s
9. Sansa F 2.108s
10. Snow M 2.134s

Possible Solution: I thought about moving each time to an array position and sort them out within the array and then rewrite the file. The thing is, I have no idea how to manipulate the code in that way. Any help will be appreciated.

*Note: the file is not supposed to display the position's number before the name

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a structure:

```
struct Entry
{
  std::string name;
  unsigned int seconds;
};
```

Now overload `operator <` to enable the sort:

```
struct Entry
{
    bool  operator<(const Entry& e)
    {
       if (name == e.name)
       {
         return seconds < e.seconds;
       }
       else
       {
         return name < e.name;
       }
    }
    std::string name;
    unsigned int seconds;
};
```

Now you can create vector to hold all the names:

```
std::vector<Entry> students;
```

And you can use `std::sort` on the vector.  (Look up the syntax of `std::sort`).

If your smart, you'll research on how to write a vector to a file, rather than posting here. (Hint:  it's been answered several times on StackOverflow).